# "Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects" warning

Tags: objective-c, accelerometer

I am trying to start the accelerometer and send a message to the user based on the accelerometer's data values. However, when I am trying to initialize accelerometer processes, I get the following warning: "Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.04;
self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates;
[self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatestoQueue:[NSOperationQueue current
Queue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error)
```

I get the error on line 6. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I believe `startAccelerometerUpdates` has arguments, check the API.

Comment: I fixed it already (see the accepted answer below), but thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line:

```
self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates;
```

should be:

```
[self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
```

Don't use property syntax to call a method.

Comment: thanks for your help, but now I'm getting an expected identifier error on the same line.

Comment: Add an update to your question by copying and pasting the line of code causing the new error.